# SequelizeJs using Op.and query and Sequelize.fn

Tags: sequelize.js

I'd like to search all lines by using a date query.

**My code :**

```
async function getSellsOfAperiod(day, month, year) {
  var whereSell = [];

  whereSell.push({
    state: 1
  });

  console.log(day, month, year); // => 3 7 2023

  whereSell.push(models.Sequelize.where(models.Sequelize.fn('MONTH', models.Sequelize.col('sell.updatedAt')), month + 1));
  whereSell.push(models.Sequelize.where(models.Sequelize.fn('YEAR', models.Sequelize.col('sell.updatedAt')), year));

  if (day) {
    whereSell.push(models.Sequelize.where(models.Sequelize.fn('DAY', models.Sequelize.col('sell.updatedAt')), day));
  }

  return SellModel.findAll({
    where: {
      [Op.and]: whereSell
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: SellProductModel,
        include: [
          { model: ProductModel }
        ]
      }, {
        model: SellPaiementModel
      }
    ]
  }).then(function(sells) {
    return sells;
  });
}
```

The `whereSell` is not workign as expected and I get an empty array. If I delete the `DAY` and `MONTH` query the code works...

**In my database I have one line :**

[image]